# I am facing error while starting React Native Project through EXPO-CLI. I am new to react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

EXPO CLI ERROR
    PS D:\Final Year Project\practice\rn-test-app> npm start

> @ start D:\Final Year Project\practice\rn-test-app

```
> expo start

Starting project at D:\Final Year Project\practice\rn-test-app

Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\@expo\xdl@56.2.8\src\Project.ts:1804:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ANONYMOUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-08T21_04_22_912Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try this --> "expo start --android"

Comment: I tried this, didn't work for me. But then I just downgraded my Node.js to **latest LTS** versions and it worked perfectly fine. 
thank you for help, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, updating Xcode to its latest version could do the trick. Kindly try it then initialize a new project.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, I actually I downgraded my Node.js and it worked perfectly fine.